# How to make side panel in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have been learning to create a chrome extension. I have tried hello world example and it was working fine. Now I have been trying to add custom code and make some changes in the hello world code according to my requirements.

What I am trying to create is when the user clicks on the icon in the address bar, it should open **popup.html** **below address bar** as shown in the picture. The screenshot is from extension called **raindrop.io**

They are doing is within chrome extension. When I click on the icon it opens the right drawer on top of the existing webpage and below the address bar to show all my saved bookmarks. I wanted to achieve the same effect but I don't know where to start. I have heard that there was some experimental side pane but google has removed it.

[image: Raindrop.io extension]

**EDIT**

I have taken the suggestions and tried to implement that. Now I am stuck at two places -

1. How to open the window when clicked on the icon in the address bar. Right now it just opens automatically by itself. I want it open when the user clicks on the icon.
2. I am doing all this to create a note taking the extension and I have done creating a note-taking extension but it works in popup interface but I wanted to implement in sidebar interface.

**Here is my code for -**

**A. Side Window Interface in Chrome Extension**

**manifest.json**

```
    {
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Hello World",
    "description": "This extension to test html injection",
    "version": "1.0",
    "content_scripts": [{
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "matches": [
            "https://*/*",
            "http://*/*"
        ],
        "js": ["js/jquery-1.11.3.js", "js/content-script.js"],
        "css": ["css/custom.css"]
    }],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
    ]
  }
```

**Content Script.js**

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe'); 
iframe.style.background = "green";
iframe.style.height = "100%";
iframe.style.width = "360px";
iframe.style.position = "fixed";
iframe.style.top = "0px";
iframe.style.right = "0px";
iframe.style.zIndex = "9000000000000000000";
iframe.frameBorder = "none"; 
 
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

**B. Note Taking App Extension**

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>SideNotes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="toolbar">
          <p id="title">S I D E N O T E S </p> 
          <img id="logo" src="image/icon.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div id="all-notes">
            <ul id="todo-items"></ul>
        </div>
        <div id="take-note">
            <form id="new-todo-form" method="POST" action="#">
                <textarea id="new-todo"></textarea>
                <input type="image" src="image/done.svg" id="submitButton">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/db.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Screenshot of my app, it works locally**
[image]

Comment: I think you need use [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) for that.The Content Scripts allow you add content to a page and you will be able to do a div with side style and effects.

Comment: There are no such panels in Chrome. Opera has the feature. Anyway, this is not a popup but just an injected html element as you can see in the element inspector upon rightclicking the "panel".

Comment: you can debug thar extension.

Comment: @PedroGámez Thanks for the reply. I have done exactly you ask and now I need some more help. Please see my edits .. thanks again.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There is no right-side panel in chrome extension API.

But you may do it in the same way that your example extension does:

1. Create `background.js` listening messages from the tab
2. Create a content script sends the message to `background.js` if the tab is injectable (if you need your extension work correct on system pages)
3. If tab is injectable, with `chrome.tabs.executeScript` inject your menu div to the page / inject listener, which opens your menu.

### More details about how to do it below.

1. Create `background.js` listening browser icon clicks and notify your content script about clicks.
2. Prevent showing of `popup.html` in default popup.

**manifest.js**

```
....
"browser_action": {
},
"background": {
    "scripts":["background.js"]
},
...
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id,"toggle");
});
```

3. In content-script.js create an invisible iframe, with your popup.html (with `zero width` on with `display:none;` style). I use `zero width` because of you may want to animate your menu display by jquery as example extension does.
4. In content-script add message listener for receive messages sent from `background.js` script.
5. When receiving the message, show or hide menu block

**content-script.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender){
    if(msg == "toggle"){
        toggle();
    }
});

var iframe = document.createElement('iframe'); 
iframe.style.background = "green";
iframe.style.height = "100%";
iframe.style.width = "0px";
iframe.style.position = "fixed";
iframe.style.top = "0px";
iframe.style.right = "0px";
iframe.style.zIndex = "9000000000000000000";
iframe.frameBorder = "none"; 
iframe.src = chrome.extension.getURL("popup.html")

document.body.appendChild(iframe);

function toggle(){
    if(iframe.style.width == "0px"){
        iframe.style.width="400px";
    }
    else{
        iframe.style.width="0px";
    }
}
```

6. Make popup.html and scripts you load from extension context visible for browser HTML context:

**manifest.json**

```
"web_accessible_resources": ["popup.html"]
```

### Read more

1. Chrome Tabs API: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs
2. Chrome message passing: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging
3. Browser action click processing: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#event-onClicked
4. Content script injection: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/executeScript

Comment: .Please check my updates and suggest me how to proceed.

Comment: Updated my answer with example. I hope now it answers both of your questions :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have completed my first chrome extension.

Comment: Is it possible for this iframe to push the actual page to the side? Basically reducing the width of the current page

Comment: There is no universal way to do it as I know. You may inject CSS to the page, so you may play with CSS to decrease display page size, like set padding-right for body block, set max-width for fixed-positioned blocks, but there are many sites now uses JS-based blocks position, calculated with body.offsetWidth and this method will not work right for it.

Comment: Great answer, but what can you do if the tab is not injectable?

Comment: There is no common way to inject JS to a non-injectable page... You may check if the page is a non-injectable and open bar in a popup window on that case

Comment: I just found below extension which does that, not sure how complicated is it to implement this feature in 2020? 

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-sidebar/jdbnofccmhefkmjbkkdkfiicjkgofkdh?hl=en

Comment: I will check it and will update my article if there is something new in API.

Comment: Anyone know how to do this when using a React app? The above results in the iframe being rendered 3 times when using React.

Comment: Chrome now has a built in side panel feature, see my post below.

Answer (score 14):

The same side panel example with `"manifest_version": 3`, as version 2 is [deprecated](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv2-sunset/).

manifest.json (change `EXTENTION-KEY`):

```
{
...
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "action": {},
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": [
            "https://*/*",
            "http://*/*"
        ],
        "js": ["side-panel.js"]
      }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
      {
        "resources": ["popup.html" ],
        "matches": ["https://*/*", "http://*/*"],
        "extension_ids": ["<EXTENTION-KEY>"]
      }
    ]
  }
```

background.js:

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(tab => {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id,"toggle");
  console.log('message sent');
});
```

side-panel.js:

```
console.log("side-panel script loaded");

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender){
    if(msg == "toggle"){
        console.log("message received");
        toggle();
    }
})

var iframe = document.createElement('iframe'); 
iframe.style.background = "green";
iframe.style.height = "100%";
iframe.style.width = "0px";
iframe.style.position = "fixed";
iframe.style.top = "0px";
iframe.style.right = "0px";
iframe.style.zIndex = "9000000000000000000";
iframe.style.border = "0px"; 
iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("popup.html")

document.body.appendChild(iframe);

function toggle(){
    if(iframe.style.width == "0px"){
        iframe.style.width="400px";
    }
    else{
        iframe.style.width="0px";
    }
}
```

popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    Content
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8):

Chrome has now launched its [side panel](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/sidePanel/) with version 114 and above, you can set a page just like you would with a popup or options page. I've written a [blog post](https://dev.to/jgrisafe/interacting-with-web-content-using-chromes-new-side-panel-extension-feature-4ock) with a clonable repository on how you can also use content scripts and dynamically display user interactions by passing messages through [port messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/#connect).

[image]

Comment: Does not yet work on Brave

Comment: Should work now on Brave @jessems