# Messaging from a web page to a panel and display the message in the panel

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I enjoy developing chrome extensions. After I added a panel to an extension, I aimed to display messages sent from a web page. To make my story short, I want to make one-way communication from a web page to an extension, and eventually render the message in the panel. I have my folder and files structures in git repository below.

https://github.com/iminsik/chromeExtension/tree/master/SendMessageToExtension

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: You'll prolly be using [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) are JavaScript files that run in the context of web pages. By using the standard Document Object Model (DOM), they can read details of the web pages the browser visits, or make changes to them. Content scripts have limits too (check the doc). Additional reading from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39610205/how-to-make-side-panel-in-chrome-extension).

Answer (score 0):

it can be done by sending a message from the web page to the content script and 
please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20716493/6738841