# Chrome Extension - Launch in Window and/or iFrame

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

As I understand, it's not possible to inject an open tab with an iFrame if it's a system page. 
Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39610205/how-to-make-side-panel-in-chrome-extension/39627099) for reference I have my extension opening as an iFrame. However I would like the extension to open as a popup (what seems to be  default behaviour for most extension) **if** the tab is not injectable.

I would presume it's a function that I could call in the `background.js` file, instead of sending a message to the `content-script.js` but looking for the [Docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/) I can't find anything relevant.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(){
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id,"toggle");
})});
```

SimilarWeb do a nice example of this.
-Clicking on SimilarWeb when there is just a blank tab:

[image: Clicking on SimilarWeb when there is just a blank tab]

-Clicking on SimilarWeb with a website loaded in a tab:

[image]

This sort of works, but only once each time the browser is opened `background.js` -

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function () {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
    if (tabs[0].url.includes("chrome://")) {
      chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup: "index.html"});
    } else {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, "toggle");
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Messaging would work if you have declared `"content_scripts"` with a script that has chrome.runtime.onMessage listener: you can check chrome.runtime.lastError in the callback of sendMessage. BTW no need for query(), just use the `tab` parameter of [onClicked](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#event-onClicked) callback.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but messaging is already working as I stated, it's knowing how to call the app as a Popup rather than an iFrame that is the issue?

Comment: I guess you can remove "default_popup" from manifest.json and use chrome.browserAction.onClicked in the background script. Another listener chrome.tabs.onUpdated would send a message to the tab on URL changes and if there's no response it would call chrome.browserAction.setPopup on this tab id only.

Comment: The problem with this approach, it takes two clicks for the popup to open?

Comment: Eh? No it shouldn't because onUpdated runs before the icon is clicked.

Comment: Perhaps I've miss-understood? I've added my code to a Plunker to help get how it's looking https://plnkr.co/edit/IcB3hMVisJCmr4k24LE0?p=info

Comment: setPopup should be used inside onUpdated.

Comment: But that means it will run everytime that tab is updated - https://plnkr.co/edit/GPWajFGMqDZznIqee6d1?p=info

Comment: And why is that a problem? P.S. 1) query() is not needed and will be wrong when the tab is inactive, simply use `tab` parameter of onUpdated, 2) See the documentation for setPopup and use a tabId parameter.

Comment: Im sorry I’m not following you. Could you update the plnkr to show what you mean? I’ve been stuck on this for days now and pretty sure I’ve gone grey because of it 